# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start using httpstaticfiles

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have the following code :

Its a .net web api code.

Program.cs

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Image"))

});
```

If I remove the following code

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Image"))

});

it works, But i need to have a static file called image and some images in it.
```

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain it more clear? "If I remove the following code,it works, But i need to have a static file called image and some images in it. " ?

Comment: Besides, you can read [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by setting the "Copy to Output Directory" property of each static file to "Copy Always".